# Modal slide animation only works when I open it but I want the effect also when I close it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a modal with a slide animation when I open the modal. But I want the effect to be applied when I close the modal.

**Goal:** Slide animation works when open and close the modal.

**Here is my code:**

```js
const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
const btnFooterModal = document.getElementById("myBtn");
const btnCloseFooterModal = document.querySelector("#myModal .close");

btnFooterModal.addEventListener('click', function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
});

btnCloseFooterModal.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.style.display = "none";
});

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 11; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: slideIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}
.close {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
}
.modal-header, .modal-footer {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.modal-footer {
  color: white;
}

#editor-container {
  height: 200px;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="close">CLOSE!!!!</button>             
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="">
            <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
        </div>      
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: always a problem to animate from display none! To put on: first you put the element with opacity to 0, after display block (little timeout 200ms here), now you can animate. To put off: you animate till opacity 0, now you display none. If you display none only it's a on/off situation, ni transition, no animation

Comment: please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58474192/795683

Comment: @SainPradeep thank you for comment. it was helpful too. II understood the problem after readed the answer from the linked question. I will rewrite my code. Merci